# How to get equivalent ANOVA in R for a model with and without a random effect?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, generalized-least-squares

My question is:

Is there a way to either force `Anova()` to somehow analyze `gls` objects (which internally are almost identical to `lme` objects), or force `Anova()` to honor the `test.statistics='F'` argument, or at least do a valid type-II sum of squares by hand on an `lme` and a `gls` object?

Why:

I'm trying to get Anova output in the same format for an `lm` or `aov` or `gls` object and an `lme` object that uses the same fixed effects formula but in addition has random effects. If I use `Anova()` from the `car` package, I get F-statistics for `aov` and `lm` objects but Chi-square statistics for `lme` objects, and it doesn't work at all for `gls` objects [1].

If I use `anova.gls()` and `anova.lme()` then they do both return F-statistics, but they use type-III or type-I sum of squares and I'm trying to use type-II.

[1]:  Gives error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found` where y is the response variable... this can be traced to the attribute for `model.matrix()` for `gls` objects failing to have an `assign` attribute.

Comment: See here for Type II testing with `gls` fitted models: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/53041/8402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I shouldn't even be concerned about the type of sum of squares if all I'm trying to do is compare a gls and a mixed-effect model with the same fixed effects. The only contrast in this comparison is between those two models. When invoked on more than one object, R's `anova()` function is just a likelihood ratio test. If I include more than two objects, the contrast is always going to be backward difference coding (i.e. each model minus its predecessor).

If `fm2` is an lme fit, the following does work:

```
gfm2<-gls(model=eval(fm2$call$fixed),data=eval(fm2$call$data));
anova(gfm2,fm2);
```

The problem with `Anova()` not working with gls fits I think is a bug, and as of car 2.0.15 still has not been fixed.

Comment: I didn't understand you wanted to test a submodel. It would have been more clear with a piece of code :)