# Which are the correct sum of squares for repeated measures ? (balanced example)

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, manova, degrees-of-freedom, sums-of-squares

Below are three ways to fit a MANOVA model in R and to extract ANOVA tables from the fitted model. The design is balanced. All methods give different results.

The data are 5 groups of 4 individuals with three repeated measures shown in figure below

[image: ldat dataset]

and simulated with the following R code:

**R code:**

```
library(ez)
library(nlme)
library(lattice)

##################################
### BALANCED DESGIN ##############
##################################
groups <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
n.groups <- length(groups)
n.individuals <- rep(4,n.groups) # four individuals per group
id <- unlist(lapply(1:n.groups, function(i) paste0(groups[i],1:n.individuals[i]))) # individual id
n <- length(id)
set.seed(666) # diabolic seed
dat <- data.frame(id=id,
           group=rep(groups, each=4),
           x=round(rnorm(n,2),1),
           y=round(rnorm(n,4),1),
           z=round(rnorm(n,6),1))
ldat <- melt(dat, id=c("id","group")) # data in long format 
xtabs( ~ group+variable, data=ldat) # check design 
# plot data: 
xyplot(value ~ variable | group, groups=id, data=ldat,
       panel = function(...){
          panel.grid(h=-1,v=-3)
          panel.superpose(..., type = "o", lty=2, pch=16)
        }
)


#### 1st method : car package ####
mfit <- lm( cbind(x,y,z)~group, data=dat )
idata <- data.frame(variable=c("x","y","z"))
aov.carII <- Anova(mfit, idata=idata, idesign=~variable, type="II")
aov.carIII <- Anova(mfit, idata=idata, idesign=~variable, type="III")

#### 2nd method : ez package ####
aov.ezI <- ezANOVA(data = ldat,
               dv = value,
               wid = id,
               within = .(variable),
               between = group,
               type=1
)
aov.ezII <- ezANOVA(data = ldat,
                   dv = value,
                   wid = id,
                   within = .(variable),
                   between = group,
                   type=2
)
aov.ezIII <- ezANOVA(data = ldat,
                   dv = value,
                   wid = id,
                   within = .(variable),
                   between = group,
                   type=3
)

### 3rd method : generalized least-squares fitting  ###
gfit <- gls(value ~ group*variable, data=ldat, 
            correlation=corSymm(form= ~ 1 | id),
            weights=varIdent(form = ~1 | variable))
```

**Comparison of ANOVA tables:**

With `gls()` there are two possible ANOVA tables:

```
>  two possible ANOVA tables with gls :
> anova(gfit, type="sequential")
Denom. DF: 45 
numDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)        1 1401.9971  <.0001
group              4    2.3793  0.0658
variable           2   79.5687  <.0001
group:variable     8    1.4759  0.1929
> anova(gfit, type="marginal") # differs from sequential except for interaction
Denom. DF: 45 
numDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)        1 23.527654  <.0001
group              4  1.383566  0.2548
variable           2 14.166517  <.0001
group:variable     8  1.475904  0.1929
```

The type I ANOVA with `ez` (type I is not available with `car`):

```
> #########################
> ### TYPE I STATISTICS ###
> #########################
> aov.ezI$ANOVA  # close to sequential anova(gfit)
Effect DFn DFd         F            p p<.05       ges
1          group   4  15  1.996615 1.467733e-01       0.1651121
2       variable   2  30 80.595661 8.605897e-13     * 0.7715479
3 group:variable   8  30  1.093567 3.945923e-01       0.1549055

> # car: no Type I available
```

The type II ANOVA:

```
> ##########################
> ### TYPE II STATISTICS ###
> ##########################
> aov.ezII$ANOVA # identical to Type I ez
Effect DFn DFd         F            p p<.05       ges
2          group   4  15  1.996615 1.467733e-01       0.1651121
3       variable   2  30 80.595661 8.605897e-13     * 0.7715479
4 group:variable   8  30  1.093567 3.945923e-01       0.1549055

> aov.carII # car is close to ez but differs except for the first factor

Type II Repeated Measures MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
Df test stat approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)
(Intercept)     1   0.98072   763.01      1     15 2.810e-14 ***
group           4   0.34744     2.00      4     15    0.1468
variable        1   0.91386    74.26      2     14 3.519e-08 ***
group:variable  4   0.51812     1.31      8     30    0.2758
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The type III ANOVA :

```
> ##########################
> ### TYPE III STATISTICS ###
> ##########################
> aov.ezIII$ANOVA # identical to Type II except for the second factor
Effect DFn DFd         F            p p<.05       ges
2          group   4  15  1.996615 0.1467732928       0.1651121
3       variable   2  30 11.560705 0.0001895724     * 0.3263455
4 group:variable   8  30  1.093567 0.3945922933       0.1549055

> aov.carIII # identical to Type II except for the second factor and intercept

Type III Repeated Measures MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
Df test stat approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)
(Intercept)     1   0.92734  191.436      1     15 6.038e-10 ***
group           4   0.34744    1.997      4     15 0.1467733
variable        1   0.65384   13.222      2     14 0.0005956 ***
group:variable  4   0.51812    1.311      8     30 0.2757596
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here is in addition the SAS output which does not depend on the chosen type (tpes I, II and III yield the same table):

```
proc mixed data=ldat ;
class id group variable ;
model value = group variable group*variable / s htype=2 ; 
repeated variable / subject=id type=un ; 
run;quit;
```

[image: sas table]

I am particularly interested in Type II sum of squares. The different ANOVA tables are close from each other but there are some differences (the F value and/or degrees of freedom). I'd like to understand these differences.

For the `ez` package I don't even know whether the results are given under the sphericity assumption.

Answer (score 3):

#### I'm afraid SAS gives "wrong" Type II test statistics.

I have learnt a lot of things.

### Type II hypothesis

According to [these slides by G. Monette and J.
Fox](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2009/slides/Monette+Fox.pdf)
the Type II test of an "effect" corresponds to a test for the nullity of a multivariate linear hypothesis about the parameters, say $H_0\colon\{L_{1\mid 2}\beta=0\}$ for a certain matrix $L_{1 \mid 2}$.

Actually $H_0$ is a ``conditional'' hypothesis (see the slides) and $L_{1\mid 2}$ depends on the asymptotic covariance matrix $V$ of $\hat\beta$.

For mixed models and/or models with a repeated structure the $L_{1\mid 2}$ matrix is obtained by estimating $V$,
but for classical linear models the $V$ matrix is proportional to ${(X'X)}^{-1}$ and there's no need to estimate it.

### Classical linear model example

Consider for instance a classical two-way ANOVA model:

```
> library(car)
> dat <- Soils[-c(1,2),] # delete two rows of the Soils dataset
> xtabs(~Contour+Depth,data=dat) # the design is unbalanced
            Depth
Contour      0-10 10-30 30-60 60-90
  Depression    4     4     4     4
  Slope         4     4     4     4
  Top           2     4     4     4
> fit <- lm(pH~Contour*Depth, data=dat)
```

I have written a function which computes the $L_{1 \mid 2}$ matrix which is valid for any model with two crossed fixed factors `facA`and `facB` as long as the `vcov()`function returns the estimated asymptotic covariance matrix :

```
L12matrix <- function(fit, facA, facB, V=vcov(fit)){
  coefs <- names(coef(fit))
  facA.match <- str_detect(coefs,facA)
  L1 <- NULL
  p <- length(facA.match)
  for(i in 1:p){
    if(facA.match[i]){
      l <- rep(0,p)
      l[i] <- 1
      L1 <- rbind(L1,l)
    }  
  }
  rownames(L1) <- coefs[facA.match]
  facAB.match <- facA.match & str_detect(coefs,facB)
  L2 <- NULL
  for(i in 1:p){
    if(facAB.match[i]){
      l <- rep(0,p)
      l[i] <- 1
      L2 <- rbind(L2,l)
    }  
  }
  rownames(L2) <- coefs[facAB.match]
  L12 <- t(car:::ConjComp(t(L2),t(L1), V))
return(L12)
}
```

And indeed, with the `linearHypothesis()` function we get the same results as the `Anova()` function:

```
> L12 <- L12matrix(fit,"Contour","Depth")
> linearHypothesis(fit,L12) 
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis: ...

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: pH ~ Contour * Depth

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     36 5.6592                           
2     34 5.3003  2   0.35891 1.1511 0.3283

 
> L12 <- L12matrix(fit,"Depth","Contour")
> linearHypothesis(fit,L12)
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis: .... 

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: pH ~ Contour * Depth

  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     37 18.3119                                  
2     34  5.3003  3    13.012 27.822 2.847e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> Anova(fit)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: pH
               Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
Contour        0.3589  2  1.1511    0.3283    
Depth         13.0116  3 27.8220 2.847e-09 ***
Contour:Depth  0.5268  6  0.5633    0.7564    
Residuals      5.3003 34                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### A GLS example

Consider the simulated data and the fitted `gls` model of my previous post:

```
groups <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
n.groups <- length(groups)
n.individuals <- rep(4,n.groups) # four individuals per group
id <- unlist(lapply(1:n.groups, function(i) paste0(groups[i],1:n.individuals[i]))) # individual id
n <- length(id)
set.seed(666) # diabolic seed
dat <- data.frame(id=id,
                  group=rep(groups, each=4),
                  x=round(rnorm(n,2),1),
                  y=round(rnorm(n,4),1),
                  z=round(rnorm(n,6),1))
ldat <- melt(dat, id=c("id","group")) # data in long format 

##
glsfit <- gls(value ~ group*variable, data=ldat,  
            correlation=corSymm(form= ~ 1 | id),
            weights=varIdent(form = ~1 | variable))
```

The Type II test of the `group` factor is performed as follows:

```
> L12 <- L12matrix(glsfit, "group", "variable")
> linearHypothesis(glsfit, L12)
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis: ...

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: value ~ group * variable

  Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1                       
2  4 9.5172    0.04939 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here the `linearHypothesis()`function has returned the *Wald $\chi^2$-test statistics* for $H_0$, and
the  *Wald $F$-test statistics* is simply obtained by dividing by the degrees of freedom:

```
> 9.5172/4
[1] 2.3793
```

Unfortunately the `Anova()` function from the `car` package does not work for `gls` fitted models.
But here the Type II Wald $F$-test statistic is equal to the Type I Wald $F$-test statistic because the design is balanced, and this statistic is returned by the `anova()` function:

```
> anova(glsfit)
Denom. DF: 45 
               numDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)        1 1401.9971  <.0001
group              4    2.3793  0.0658
variable           2   79.5687  <.0001
group:variable     8    1.4759  0.1929
```

If the design were not balanced then the Type II Wald $F$-test statistic can be obtained by inverting the order of the factors:

```
gfit.reverse <- update(gfit, model = value ~ variable*group)
anova(gfit.reverse)
```

Note that the `L12matrix(glsfit, ...)` command only uses the fitted model `glsfit` to get the parameters names and to get the asymptotic covariance matrix from the default value of the `V` argument.
Thus we would get the same results by typing :

```
L12 <- L12matrix(fit, "group", "variable", V=vcov(glsfit))
```

### The SAS bug ?

Now, what's the problem with SAS ?
For a classical linear model such as `fit`, no problem: it gives the same results as the `Anova()` function.

But for a model with a repeated structure, such as `glsfit`, the
SAS output is obtained as follows with the R tools introduced above:

```
> # SAS result :
> lmfit <- lm(value ~ group*variable, data=ldat)
> L12 <- L12matrix(glsfit, "group", "variable", V=vcov(lmfit))
> linearHypothesis(glsfit, L12)
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis: ...

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: value ~ group * variable

  Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1                       
2  4 7.9864    0.09208 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Divide `7.9864` by `4` and you find the SAS output :
[image]

In other words, SAS gives the Wald $F$-test statistic for $H_0:\colon\{L_{1\mid 2}\beta=0\}$ but by taking the
$L_{1\mid 2}$ matrix obtained with
the covariance matrix of the classical linear model obtained by ignoring the repeated structure.

### Conclusion

Is it a "bug" with SAS, something wrong ? That depends whether the SAS developers have an interpretation of their Type II table but it seems to be a naïve generalization of the classical linear model to more general linear models, whereas J. Fox and G. Monette provide in their slides a well interpretable general approach to Type II hypotheses (is it an old or  a recent approach ? I'd like to know).

Comment: Continuation here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53045/monette-foxs-conditional-hypotheses/

Answer (score 1):

#### About the difference between Type II and Type III with the car package:

In spite of the balanced design there is a difference because Type III tests depend on the specified contrasts. With orthogonal constrats there's no difference:

```
> mfit <- update(mfit, contrasts=list(group=contr.sum))
> Anova(mfit, idata=idata, idesign=~variable, type="III")

Type III Repeated Measures MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
               Df test stat approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)     1   0.98072   763.01      1     15 2.810e-14 ***
group           4   0.34744     2.00      4     15    0.1468    
variable        1   0.91386    74.26      2     14 3.519e-08 ***
group:variable  4   0.51812     1.31      8     30    0.2758    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Finally with this example we could also suspect that SAS provides the Pillai statistic for factor `group` and the Wald statistic for factor `variable`. Yet I don't really know what's exactly going on... I will edit my posts in case of further understanding.